# mybatis + springboot 2.3.0 - Could not resolve type alias issue

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I wrote below code to put Book list of all Stores in StoreBooks.

But the following exception raised.
org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'StoreResult'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: StoreResult

I changed 'resultType= "StoreResult"' to 'resultType= "com.test.StoreBooks"' then there was no exception, but StoreBooks had empty books list.

How can I solve this issue?

```java
<mapper namespace="com.test.Mapper">

  <resultMap type="com.test.Book" id="Books">
    <result property="id" column="ID"/>
    <result property="storeId" column="STORE_ID"/>
    <result property="name" column="NAME"/>
    <result property="price" column="PRICE"/>
  </resultMap>

  <resultMap type="com.test.StoreBooks" id="StoreResult">
    <result property="id" column="ID"/>
    <result property="name" column="NAME"/>
    <collection property="books" resultMap="Books" />
  </resultMap>

  <select id= "retrieveStoreBookList" parameterType= "map" resultType= "StoreResult">
    SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, B.ID, B.NAME, B.PRICE
       FROM T_STORE A
      JOIN T_BOOK B ON A.ID = B.STORE_ID
  </select>

</mapper>


@Data
public class Book {
    String id;
    String storeId;
    String name;
    String price;
}

@Data
public class StoreBooks {
    String id;
    String name;
    List<Book> books;
}
```

Comment: In the `<select>`, change `resultType="StoreResult"` to `resultMap="StoreResult"`

Comment: Also, its good practice to use `<id property="id" column="ID"/>` for when you get into more complex queries and collections/associations.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Jeff and kendavidson.